# How to install Calibre on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, calibre

Im trying to install Calibre e-book manager on my computer, i'm a newbie to linux and i dont know where the "installation directory" is....Here are the commands that they have in order to install it...

```
sudo python -c "import sys; py3 = sys.version_info[0] > 2; u = __import__('urllib.request' if py3 else 'urllib', fromlist=1); exec(u.urlopen('http://status.calibre-ebook.com/linux_installer').read()); main()"
```

"One can also avoid having the installer script ask for the installation directory by specifying it in the install command itself, as shown below:"

```
sudo python -c "import sys; py3 = sys.version_info[0] > 2; u = __import__('urllib.request' if py3 else 'urllib', fromlist=1); exec(u.urlopen('http://status.calibre-ebook.com/linux_installer').read()); main(install_dir='/path/to/your/library')"
```

[Source](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux)

Comment: flatpak (flathub) works well for installing

Answer (score 12):

Install it by using the Command Line.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open the Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/calibre2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

Once done, click on bre in dash, and follow the screens.

[image: calibre welcome wizard]

[image: calibre welcome wizard]

<sup>Source:LinuxG</sup>

Comment: For Precise, the PPA has been changed to `ppa:n-muench/calibre2` to reduce the clutter.

Comment: Check this one: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/calibre, the ppa is this (as 2020-02): `ppa:jonathonf/calibre`

Answer (score 3):

The package `calibre` contained in Ubuntu repositories is slightly outdated. As of today the best way to install the latest version of Calibre is to run :

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py | sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
```

On the downside you won't be able to update `calibre` using `apt-get upgrade`. You will need to run this command everytime you need to update `calibre` (Calibre will prompt you an updated notice).

---

For more information and installation options. Refer to Calibre [download page](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux).

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code in your Ubuntu terminal:

```bash
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh | sudo sh /dev/stdin
```

Source: [Official Site - Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux)